# git stashed problem deleted my newly changed file how to recover them?

Tags: git, github

I had a master commit in a repo.
after that I had worked on the same branch.
before I could commit.
the repo got stashed and all my new work has gone.
how to recover those new files and changes ?

Comment: Apply the stash?

Comment: [Stashing and Cleaning in Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) should help.

Answer (score 0):

To recover those files, first find out the stash entry you want by using:

```
$ git stash list
```

then, to apply the stash and keep it, use:

```
$ git stash apply stash@{n}
```

or to apply the stash and remove it, use:

```
$ git stash pop stash@{n}
```

where n is the stash index corresponding to the stash you want.
More info here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash